# Representing signed kernels as linear bounded operators

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X, \mathcal{A})$ be a measurable space and
denote by $B$ the Banach space of bounded $\mathcal{A}$-measurable functions $f : X \to \mathbb{R}$ with the supremum norm $\lVert f \rVert_\infty = \sup_{x \in X} |f(x)|$ and by $ca$ the Banach space of signed measures $\mu : \mathcal{A} \to \mathbb{R}$ of bounded variation with the total variation norm $\lVert \mu \rVert_{TV} = \sup_{A \in \mathcal{A}} |\mu|(A)$.
A signed kernel on $(X, \mathcal{A})$ is a map $K : X \times \mathcal{A} \to \mathbb{R}$ with the properties

(i) $K(\cdot, A) \in B$ for all $A \in \mathcal{A}$ and

(ii) $K(x, \cdot) \in ca$ for all $x \in X$.

The space $\mathcal{K}$ of signed kernels on $(S, \mathcal{A})$ is a vector space as a linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{X \times \mathcal{A}}$. Define a multiplication operation on $\mathcal{K}$ by $(K_1 K_2) (x, B) := \int K_1(x, du) K_2(u, B)$
where the integral of a bounded measurable function $g$ w.r.t. to a finite signed measure of bounded variation $\nu$ with Jordan decomposition $\nu = \nu^+ + \nu^-$ is defined as usual by $\int d\nu \, g := \int g \, d\nu := \int g \, d\nu^+ + \int g\, d\nu^-$. Then $\mathcal{K}$ is an algebra (by linearity of integral and Fubini for signed measures).

Every $K \in \mathcal{K}$ induces a bounded linear operator $F_K \in L(B)$ by $f \mapsto (F_K f)(x) := \int K(x, du) f(u)$ and a bounded linear operator $M_K \in L(ca)$ by $\mu \mapsto (\mu M_K)(B) := \int \mu(du) K(u, B)$. Moreover, when considering $L(B)$ and $L(ca)$ as (Banach) algebras then these maps $F$ and $M$ are algebra homomorphisms.

Questions:

(1) Are these maps injective? In other words, can we consider $\mathcal{K}$ as a subspace of operators in $L(B)$ or $L(ca)$? If not, under which properties on the measurable space $(S, \mathcal{A})$ are they injective? Or maybe I should better concentrate on certain topological spaces $S$ with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra and consider instead of $B$ and $ca$ the spaces of continuous bounded functions $C_b$ and regular measures $rca$ and call for some Riesz representation theorem?

(2) In case $F$ and $M$ are injective, then we can equip $\mathcal{K}$ with two norms namely the operator norm of $L(B)$ and that of $L(ca)$. Are these norms equivalent?

(3) Can we consider these representations of $\mathcal{K}$ as linear bounded operators on $B$ resp. on $ca$ in some sense as dual or adjoint to each other? In general, the dual $B'$ is not $ca$ and $ca'$ is not $B$. So, how can we bring in the adjoint maps $L(B) \to L(B')$ and $L(ca) \to L(ca')$ into play?

Comment: I think, in order to answer these questions, we need to consider some kind of "dual kernel" (similar to the transpose of a matrix, when considering a kernel as a generalization of finite-dimensional matrices). But I don't know what that should be.

Comment: Injectivity of $F$ and $M$ seems obvious: If $F_K=0$ and $A\in \mathcal A$ you have $K(x,A)= \int I_A(u) K(x,du) = F_K(I_A)(x)=0$ for all $x\in X$. If  $M_K=0$ and $x\in X$ you get $K(x,A)= \int K(u,A) \delta_x(du) =M_K(\delta_x)(A)=0$ for all $A\in \mathcal A$.

Comment: @Jochen Oh yes, really obvious, when one is not overwhelmed by the overload of the notation. So we can identify $\mathcal{K}$ with the linear subspaces of operators on $B$ resp. $ca$ that are representable by signed kernels (generalizing integral kernels $K(s,t) \mu(dt)$ being absolutely continuous w.r.t. some fixed measure $\mu$).

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, but I believe to have calculated $\|F_K\|_{L(B)}=\|M_K\|_{L(ca)}=\sup\lbrace \|K(x,\cdot)\|_{ca}:x\in X\rbrace$.

Comment: @Jochen perfectly, with your mentioned representations $K(x, A) = F_K(I_A)(x) = M_K(\delta_x)(A)$ this equality of norms is again obvious. So we can equip $\mathcal{K}$ with the canonical norm $\lVert K \rVert := \sup_{x \in X} \sup_{A \in \mathcal{A}} |K(x,A)|$. Then $\mathcal{K}$ embedds isometrically into $L(B)$ and $L(ca)$ by $F$ resp. $M$. So it remains (3) as a generalization of the adjointness in the finite-dimensional case of left- and right-multiplication with a matrix by transposition. What should be the "transposition" of such kernels $K(x, A)$?